# Assign and copy value to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to assign the a input(2) with the same value of another input(3).

I have this working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            gform.addFilter( 'gform_list_item_pre_add', function ( clone ) {
                clone.find('td:eq(1) input').val('your new value');
                return clone;
            } );

    </script>
```

I need to replace 'your new value' with the value of the 3rd input:

```
clone.find('td:eq(1) input').val('td:eq(3) input').val());
```

But it breaks the code. Can you advise where I am going wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to make the value of `td:eq(1) input` equal the value of `td:eq(3) input`?

Comment: Define 'breaks'. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Yes Tom I am the need to be the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$` from your replacement line:

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_list_item_pre_add', function ( clone ) {
    var newVal = clone.find('td:eq(3) input').val();
    clone.find('td:eq(1) input').val(newVal);
    return clone;
});
```

Comment: Hi Guys this is my complete code now: 

     `gform.addFilter( 'gform_list_item_pre_add', function ( clone ) {
     var newVal = clone.find('td:eq(3) input').val();
     clone.find('td:eq(1) input').val(newVal);
     return clone;
     } );`

The value is not getting duplicated though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input3_val = clone.find('td:eq(3) input').val();
clone.find('td:eq(1) input').val(input3_val);
```